# Horizontal Sub Menu WordPress Underscores Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Im having some issue with this sub-menu I need it to look like this

[image]

Right now it looks like this http://paramountwell.staging.wpengine.com/

By Default the sub-menu parent is set to relative and the sub-menu is set to absolute. I tried moving the position: relative to the header container. Which sort of achieves what I want but then the sub-menu is always shown even when the parent isn't being hovered. Anyone help would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 CSS rules you need to change.

Then the submenu needs some better formatting.

```css
.main-navigation ul ul {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 179px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    background-color: #106ccc;
    width: 100%;
    display: none; /* Added */
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover>ul, .main-navigation ul li.focus>ul {
    /* left: auto; */
    display: block; /* Added */
}
```